# how to export Bezier curves control points?

Tags: export, bezier-curves, blend-files

How does one export a file containing all the control points of the bezier surface in a Blender object?

Here is an image showing my work.

The .obj file I export unfortunately doesn't contain those.

I am pretty new to  blender. I don't know any python.

Blender 2.7

Comment: Please show your Blender screen images that will clarify your question.  What type of file do you want ... text, or, other?  What will the file be used for?  What other program will use this data?  The answer to those questions should be in your explanation above.  The control point data is accessible for the people who familiar with Python and Blender data representation. That includes you with time and effort.  The proposed answer below mentions addons.